# How i connect from android to another cellphone with (DUN or PAN)?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I create a simple bluetooth terminal for android and i want to connect with other cellphone not android support uuid=1115(PAN) with personal area network....and share internet connection to android.How i do this?I know for (DUN) is AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","APN"...and after dial with ATD*99***1# What is the procedure for PAN?I connected with my PC and BlueSoleil with cellphone share internet to pc...I test it again with DUN bluetooth service...

```
 AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","MYAPN"
 REPLY OK

 ATD*99***1#
 REPLY CONNECT
```

After what can i do?I can use url from my terminal?How i keep my application to backgroung and open my browser for use internet?

Answer (score 1):

For PAN, it is totally different as against the way you did for DUN which involves remote RAS-dial using the access point settings you provided (consider PPP link). PAN involves using the BNEP layer to give you the needed network connection via a virtual Bluetooth Ethernet driver/interface. There is no RAS-dial involved in PAN, and therefore you don't need the AT commands you did with DUN to initiate a connection.

For PAN to work, you need to have PAN profile supported on your phone + on your Desktop PC (let's say) as well. Imagine if you want to use the browser on your phone with no mobile data subscription or Wi-Fi not available, but you have an internet + Bluetooth enabled PC nearby, you would initiate a PAN connection from your phone to your PC. The underlying BNEP will be responsible for carrying and routing your Bluetooth packets with Ethernet frames in the ACL payload. Please refer more of the BNEP protocol to understand more.